# Errors are NOT throwing properly?

Tags: python, exception, visual-studio-2012

Okay, so this is the strangest thing I've seen happen in a pretty long time.  So, I fire up vs2012 like I normally do, and start some imports.  I have a module I'm working with, and I import it via static import from the root of my module.

```
import os
from foo.bar import bang
```

I execute these in the interpreter... and all of a sudden, my exceptions don't work.

I type in, `assert 1 == 2`, and nothing happens.  I type in `x[1]`, and nothing happens.  No x is undefined, no assertionerror, nothing.

Okay, so I restart my interpreter, and just do the assertion statement.  It works fine.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?  What could possibly be causing it?  (Yes, I know it's the imported module, but seeing as it's quite a bit of code, perhaps a place to start looking before I go diving into the depths?)

[edit]

Running commands in the interactive seem to take a long time, too-- `dir()` took like 3 seconds to come up with a list 8 or so items long.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility:

```
import sys

def hook(type, value, traceback):
    pass

sys.excepthook = hook
assert 1 == 2
```

In this case, the assert will not print anything out. You could verify this by seeing if `sys.excepthook != sys.__excepthook__`.

*Note: ipython, for example, fools with this value. So if you're testing this, make sure you just use `python` and not `ipython`.*

Comment: Very nice, sure enough, `sys.excepthook == sys.__excepthook__` returns `True`.  The question is then, what to do about it? :(

Comment: If `sys.excepthook == sys.__excepthook__`, then that means that this is not the reason for your problems. I wasn't clear about that in my post, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after reading up on the excepthook thing. :( I take back my checkvote, but I leave you with my upvote for your efforts.